# java - Как сменить версию JDK на Windows 11

Tags: java, windows, файловые-пути

У меня есть две версии `Java`. `JDK 17` и `JDK 21`, пока что, когда я пишу `java --version` в `cmd` у меня пишет:

```
java 21.0.2 2024-01-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21.0.2+13-LTS-58)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.2+13-LTS-58, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Когда я просмотрел переменную среды `Path` во вкладке **для пользователя** и во вкладке **системные переменные**, то я не увидел там путь к `JDK 21`.
Тогда я поставил в **переменную среды** `JAVA_HOME` путь к `JDK 17` и добавил в самый конец `Path` `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

[image: 1]

и после перезагрузки ПК у меня не поменялась версия `java`. При команде `java --version` в консоли мне пишет, что версия все та же 21-ая. Как мне поменять версию `JDK` на 17?

Comment: Что пишет ``where java``?

Comment: C:\Users\mattc>where java
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Users\mattc\AppData\Local\Programs\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.4.101-hotspot\bin\java.exe
D:\Java17\bin\java.exe

Comment: в самом низу `Path` стоит D:\Java17\bin\java.exe, но почему то не он срабатывает при использовании команды `java`

Comment: Странно, что при работе команды `java` срабатывает `JDK 21` т. к. её нет в пути.

Comment: Срабатывает всегда первый путь. Именно там и находится 21.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Следует отредактировать переменную `%PATH%`, удалив дубликаты ссылок на разные JRE/JDK и оставить в ней единственную ссылку через `%JAVA_HOME%`:

```
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;...
```

И соответственно в `%JAVA_HOME%` устанавливать требуемую версию.

Также можно "сохранить" пути к разным версиям:

```
SET JDK_21=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
SET JDK_17_ECLIPSE=C:\Users\mattc\AppData\Local\Programs\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.4.101-hotspot
SET JDK_17=D:\Java17

SET JAVA_HOME=%JDK_17%
```